# array sort ascending order - bubble sort

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort

I'm trying to arrange my array in an asscending order but its giving me a different value:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    const int size = 5;
                //    0  1  2  3  4
    int arr[size] = {50,20,54,12,23};

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) //! bubble sort ascending order
    {
        for (int j=i; j<5; j++)
        {   //      50        20
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                int temp = arr [j+1];
                arr [j+1] = arr [j];
                arr [j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The fact that it is not working, could it be of the empty array value (arr[6]) at the end of the loop that is messing up with the overall value? If so, it should be able to sort up till the last array size but its giving a different output instead

Output: `20 12 0 23 50`

Comment: `j+1` is out of bounds for `j = 4`.

Comment: changing `arr[j+1]` to `arr[i]` should work.

Comment: @jackw11111: That would no longer be a bubble sort.  OTOH now it isn't either.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent out of bound problems, change:

- `i<5` to `size-1`
- `j<5` to `size-1-i`
- `j=i` to `j=0`

Code:

```
int main ()
{
    const int size = 5;
                //    0  1  2  3  4
    int arr[size] = {50,20,54,12,23};

    for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++) //! bubble sort ascending order
    {
        for (int j=0; j<size-1-i; j++)
        {   //      50        20
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                int temp = arr [j+1];
                arr [j+1] = arr [j];
                arr [j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```